# Auto update of Android app without user intervention

Tags: android, auto-update, rooted-device

I know it is duplicate question, there are several topic on SO.
How to auto update the app without user intervention, even no confirmation dialog also.

Most of answer is telling without rooting the phone it is not possible.

My  doubt is if without rooting silent update is not possible then how google play is doing on every device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Play Store is part of the device firmware, and therefore it can do things that ordinary SDK applications cannot. If you build your own firmware, you can arrange to update apps without user intervention as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, without rooting it is impossible.  Google play is the only thing that can "auto-update" your app.  The user has the choice to auto-update in Google Play specifically for the app, not the developer.